# DSUM Between dates criteria not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have tried every suggestion I can find on forums but my code is getting messy!

I am using Microsoft Access (Office 365) my computer is in French, I have English installed as a secondary language.

I want to find all sales records from tblEtsySales for the second quarter of the year.  I am summing the records from the field TotalReceived using DSUM and want to filter by date.  I get an unexpected amount returned when it should be zero.

Here is my code:

```
Dim Q2 As Currency
Dim Quarter2 As String

Quarter2 = "[Sale Date] BETWEEN #01/04/2017# And #30/06/2017#"

If IsNull(Q2 = DSum("[TotalReceived]", "tblEtsySales", Quarter2)) = True Then
    MsgBox "No data for the second quarter."
    txtQ2.Value = ""
Else
    Q2 = DSum("[TotalReceived]", "tblEtsySales", Quarter2)
    txtQ2.Value = Q2
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression `#01/04/2017#` is read as 2017-01-04.

So do this:

```
Dim Q2 As Currency
Dim Quarter2 As String
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Date2 As Date

Date1 = #04/01/2017# 
Date2 = #06/30/2017# ' You can type it differently, but VBA will correct it.

Quarter2 = "[Sale Date] BETWEEN #" & Format(Date1, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Date2, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"

Q2 = DSum("[TotalReceived]", "tblEtsySales", Quarter2)

If Q2 = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No data for the second quarter."
    txtQ2.Value = Null
Else
    txtQ2.Value = Q2
End If
```

Comment: It worked, thank you that is great. :)  It didn't like Q2 = Dsum etc... when Dsum returns 0)  so I did this...

'
Dim Q2 As Currency
Dim Quarter2 As String
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Date2 As Date

Date1 = #4/1/2017#
Date2 = #6/30/2017#

Quarter2 = "[Sale Date] BETWEEN #" & Format(Date1, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Date2, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"

If IsNull(DSum("[TotalReceived]", "tblEtsySales", Quarter2)) = True Then
    Q2 = 0
Else
    Q2 = DSum("[TotalReceived]", "tblEtsySales", Quarter2)
End If

txtQ2.Value = Q2'

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off passing data parameters to a procedure to make this more flexible, but if you only need it for Q2 into perpetuity...

```
Dim Q2 As Double
Dim Quarter2 As String

Quarter2 = "[Sale Date] BETWEEN #01/04/2017# And #30/06/2017#"
Q2=DSum("[TotalReceived]", "tblEtsySales", Quarter2)

if Q2=0 then
    MsgBox "No data for the second quarter."
    txtQ2.Value = ""
else
    txtQ2.Value=Q2
end if
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.  Unfortunately it doesn't work.  I am doing the 4 quarters and the year changes automatically but I have checked this all works it just seems to be the dates?  Sale Date TotalReceived
10/01/2017 16,50 €
01/01/2017 69,63 €
22/03/2017 12,40 €
03/03/2017 69,63 €  These are the actual figures (not a lot of sales I know!) I get the right result for Q1 but Q2 and all the others come back as 98.53 euros.  I have no idea where this is from.